# Devices not receiving notification even though it is successfully sent in the logs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a simple messaging app using firebase cloud messaging service but and I am using cloud functions to handle the notifications, however whenever I test it it always says successful in the logs but the devices receive nothing

Here is the cloud function used :

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/meesages/{messageId}').onCreate(event => {
  var eventSnapshot = event.data;
  var str1 = "Sender : ";
  var str = str1.concat(eventSnapshot.child("messageOwner").val());
  console.log(str);

  var topic = "Messaging";
  var payload = {
      notification: {
          Message: eventSnapshot.child("messageText").val(),
          Sender: eventSnapshot.child("messageOwner").val()
      }
  };

  // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic,payload)
      .then(function (response) {
          // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
          // contents of response.
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });

});
```

Here is the class responsible for handling the notifications part on the android device :

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("Sender"), remoteMessage.getData().get("Message"));
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }

    private void showNotification(String Message, String Sender) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New message : " + Message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("By : " + Sender)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and yes I made sure to add the topic subscription in the mainactivity class

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Messaging");
```

so what is exactly wrong here ??

Comment: Did you define service in manifest file ?

Comment: is Device Service Still Running ?

Comment: Yes I did define the service first thing in the manifest
and yes the device service was still running

Comment: I may add that the manual push notifications are working fine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `onMessageReceived()` expects the message to have a data payload.  This is explained in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message_payload), which includes three tabs, showing notification, data, and combined payloads.  Change `notification` to `data`:

```
  var payload = {
      data: {
          Message: eventSnapshot.child("messageText").val(),
          Sender: eventSnapshot.child("messageOwner").val()
      }
  };
```

Comment: I literally spent like 4 hours without any solution
I can't thank you enough